# In a periodogram, why is the modulus squared of the DFT taken rather than the DFT itself?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

Why can't you just take the DFT itself? And how accurate is this method in spectral density estimation? Are there cases in which it is very accurate?

Comment: Because that's how it's defined. Also, how would you visualize a complex-valued 2D object? "How accurate" and "when is it very accurate" would require us to first define *accuracy*, and for that define signal classes, possibly introduce you to the theory of stochastic signals, what an autocorrelation function is and so on... too broad, I'm afraid!

Answer (score 0):

Many applications just want a strictly real value of some sort (for a simple line graph, or peak magnitude frequency estimate, etc.).  And the modulus squared is a real value; whereas the result of a DFT is a complex valued vector. (except, depending on definitions, for strictly even functions/waveforms)